# What is the second parameter of scandir()?

Tags: c

I have a program where I'm trying to use scandir(), but running into an issue that is raising a few questions for me.

According to the [man-page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scandir.3.html) for scandir(), the function takes in a "triple pointer" to a dirent struct:

```
int scandir(const char *dirp, struct dirent ***namelist,
              int (*filter)(const struct dirent *),
              int (*compar)(const struct dirent **, const struct dirent **));
```

However, the page also provides the example below:

```
#define _DEFAULT_SOURCE
       #include <dirent.h>
       #include <stdio.h>
       #include <stdlib.h>

       int
       main(void)
       {
           struct dirent **namelist;
           int n;

           n = scandir(".", &namelist, NULL, alphasort);
           if (n == -1) {
               perror("scandir");
               exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
           }

           while (n--) {
               printf("%s\n", namelist[n]->d_name);
               free(namelist[n]);
           }
           free(namelist);

           exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
       }
```

Notice that they declare a **double** pointer named *namelist* and use the "address-of" operator with it in scandir().

I'm assuming this somehow turns it into a "triple pointer"? Hoping someone can explain what's going on here with a diagram or something. I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: The 1st pointer is about pointing to the variable (`dirent` in your example) so `scandir` can assign to it, the 2nd pointer is about allocating an array, and the 3rd pointer is about allocating each element of the array (each element contains a structure with information about the file). The "triple" pointer comes from the ampersand which takes the address of the `namelist` variable.

Comment: That is quite interesting. Not sure how that works, but very interesting. What I'm concerned with, however, is how using the address-of operator turns the double pointer into a triple pointer.

Comment: The 'address-of' operator gives you back a pointer. Since your variable is declared with two pointers, when you take its address, you get back the 3rd pointer.

Comment: What do you think a pointer is? The address of an object is a pointer to an object. Given `int x0;`, do you understand what `int *x1 = &x0;` does? What about `int **x2 = &x1;`? Or `int ***x3 = &x2;`? Given any object `q` of type `T`, `&q` is the address of the object and a `T *` is a type of a thing that can hold that address.

Answer (score 0):

`&` in a declaration *in C++* means "reference to". Since this is neither C++ nor a declaration, it's irrelevant.

In an expression though, it is the unary [address-of operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access#Built-in_address-of_operator) (or the binary bitwise and operator).

From a type perspective, taking the address of something just adds (another) `*` to the type. Hence, the address of a `struct dirent **` does indeed have type `struct dirent ***`.

Comment: This question is tagged C, so there is no such thing as "reference to" and `&` in a declaration is simply invalid.

Comment: Right, I know it's the "address-of" operator, but not seeing how it essentially turns it into a triple pointer.

Comment: @kvnr: `struct dirent **` is "pointer to pointer to `struct dirent`". If you take the address of such an object, the result is a pointer to...

Comment: @kvnr do you understand how, for example, taking the address of an `int` gives you an `int *`?

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of `scandir` is to retrieve an array or 'list' of `dirent`s.

While there are a few differences between 'pointer-to-first-array-element' and an actual array (which i highly recommend to read about if you intent to use c), we might consider them equal for this case.

As such an array of `dirent` structures would be `struct dirent *namelist` (which is not the case).

But the function actually yields an indirect-list, thus an array of pointers to `dirent` structures: `struct dirent **namelist`.

This is how `namelist` is defined in the example and this also explains the access via `namelist[n]->d_name`. Since namelist is an array -> `namelist[n]` is an array-element (a pointer to dirent). The 'arrow operator' dereferences this pointer and accesses the field `d_name`.

That was the easy part, now lets look at the function call.
The documentation you linked states

> collected in array namelist which is allocated via malloc

This means that somewhere inside of `scandir` `malloc` is called and returns a pointer to the allocated memory. However the pointers value must somehow be known to the caller of `scandir`. One possibility would be to simply return it just as `malloc` does. But instead it was chosen to use an 'output-parameter'. This simply means a pointer to the variable (meaning its address) that would have received that value if it was a typical 'return-parameter'. This is where the third asterisk (*) comes from. As you know: the addressof-operator (&) just gives that address. This is why `&namelist` is passed as 'output-argument'.

To maybe better understand output-parameters think of the `scanf` function. Here also each value that you want to 'scan' is passed as output-parameter to the function. If you want to receive an integer you create an `int` variable (e.g. `int myVal;`) and pass it's address (`scanf("%d", &myVal);`). The expected parameter type would be `int *`.

Or again speaking generally:

```
<result-type> resultValue;
<return-type> returnValue = <function>(&resultValue);
```

where the function with output parameter would be defined as

```
<return-type> <function>(<result-type> *foo){...}
```

And yes, the addressof operator adds an asterisk (*) to the type (depending on the type this might be a bit more difficult then just adding the asterisk (e.g. function pointers or pointers to array (actual arrays))).
In our case `<result-val>` is `struct dirent **` and the third asterisk is added for the parameter type.

As a last note:
the returntype of `scandir` is the number of elements in the array.
Since `namelist` does not hold the length information of the array in its type, you need the return value to know how many values you can access.