# Segmentation fault and incompatible pointer type warning with scandir()

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I wrote a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65271110/what-is-the-second-parameter-of-scandir?noredirect=1#comment115393136_65271110) earlier about `scandir()`, but figured I'd make a new post since I believe the requirement is to only have one question per post.

I'm writing a program that uses `scandir()` and getting a `incompatible pointer type` warning when I run the program.

According to the [man-page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65271110/what-is-the-second-parameter-of-scandir?noredirect=1#comment115393136_65271110) for scandir(), the function takes in a "triple pointer" to a dirent struct:

```
int scandir(const char *dirp, struct dirent ***namelist,
              int (*filter)(const struct dirent *),
              int (*compar)(const struct dirent **, const struct dirent **));
```

However, the page also provides the example below:

```
#define _DEFAULT_SOURCE
       #include <dirent.h>
       #include <stdio.h>
       #include <stdlib.h>

       int
       main(void)
       {
           struct dirent **namelist;
           int n;

           n = scandir(".", &namelist, NULL, alphasort);
           if (n == -1) {
               perror("scandir");
               exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
           }

           while (n--) {
               printf("%s\n", namelist[n]->d_name);
               free(namelist[n]);
           }
           free(namelist);

           exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
       }
```

In my program, I decided to follow the example and have the code in my program below (distilled to only the statements relevant to `scandir()`):

```
int numOfDirectories = 0;
struct dirent **dirEntries;
numOfDirectories = scandir(".", &dirEntries, NULL, alphasort);
```

When I run the program, I then get the warning below:

[image: Compiler warning]

Why would it be giving me this error when I'm essentially following the example it has in the man-page?

Further, according to information received from my other post, passing in `&dirEntries` when `dirEntries` is a double-pointer should be a triple-pointer.

I did try changing the program by declaring `dirEntries` as a triple pointer:

```
int numOfDirectories = 0;
struct dirent ***dirEntries;
numOfDirectories = scandir(".", dirEntries, NULL, alphasort);
```

I don't get any compiler errors, but when I run the program I then get a `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` error.

I did have a filter function as the 3rd parameter, but decided to just set to NULL in-case it was my filter function causes the error. Still get the same `segmentation fault` error using `NULL`.

I also tried running the debugger, which it does show this:
[image: Debugger View]

Then essentially after I declare my `dirEntries` I have an if-statement that is entered and immediately runs `numOfDirectories = scandir(".", &dirEntries, NULL, alphasort);`

I'm at a loss of what is going on. Any ideas what it could be? Thank you. Appreciate your help and feedback.

Comment: Do not paste images of text. Copy and paste the exact text. You can use `<pre>` and `</pre>` tags to mark it as preformatted text.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the feedback @EricPostpischil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why would it be giving me this error when I'm essentially following the example it has in the man-page?

You are not following the example. The example declares a thing with type `struct dirent **` and passes its address, using `&`. You declare a thing with type `struct dirent **` and pass it, not its address, not using `&`.

Change your code to pass `&dirEntries`, not `dirEntries`.

> I did try changing the program by declaring dirEntries as a triple pointer: … I don't get any compiler errors, but when I run the program I then get a `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` error.

The thing you pass had the right type, but it did not have a correct value. `scandir` does not just want you to pass something of type `struct dirent **`, it wants you to pass the address of a `struct dirent **` that you provide. This is because it is going to fill in that `struct dirent **` with some value. (That value will be a `struct dirent **`; it will point to a `struct dirent *`.)

When you make `dirEntries` with `struct dirent ***dirEntries;`, you do not give it any value, so passing it as an argument is wrong. In contrast, `struct dirent **dirEntries` makes a pointer, and then passing `&dirEntries` gives the address of that pointer to `scandir`. It uses that address to put a value in `dirEntries`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.

Regarding your first point, I actually did use the address-of operator to pass the address of `struct dirent **`. 

On your second point, in a sense I see what you're saying, but having difficulty wrapping my head around it. The documentation says it want's a triple pointer, so I'm passing a triple pointer.

Comment: One thing I realized is with my "incompatible pointer type" warning, it was due to another statement later on that was just using `dirEntries` and not `&dirEntries`. So I commented that out and now everything compiles and runs correctly. Still not sure about the issue regarding double vs. triple pointer.

Comment: Re “The documentation says it want's a triple pointer, so I'm passing a triple pointer”: So? The documentation for `sqrt` says it takes a `double`, but if you do `double x; printf("%g\n", sqrt(x));`, what do you get? `x` was never initialized, so it has no determined value. When you pass `scandir` an uninitialized pointer, it gets a pointer with no determined value. When it tries to use that pointer, something goes wrong. You have to pass a particular value, not just something matching in type.